# Losing auth session in Laravel

Tags: session, laravel

In file `app/config/session.php` I've changed `lifetime` to 30 days. Using browser console I see that cookie is set correctly.

After an hour session cookie remains unchanged yet my auth session is lost.

I'm using native session driver. It's using the cookie, so as far as I understand session should remain valid till there's a cookie.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: It turns out that I didn't set "remember me" flag correctly in application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few settings in your php.ini file that look like they could be impacting this functionality.  I'm guessing the first one is probably the culprit since you are using cookies.

`session.cookie_lifetime = 0`

`session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`

`session.cache_expire = 180`

Comment: This may be the case. I've thought that Laravel handles this case.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I should set this values to be equal to 30 days right?